# In John 6, why did Jesus use a following participle in v.51, and a preceding in v.57?

Tags: john, jesus

> ειμι ο αρτος ο ζων ο εκ του ουπανου καταβας (John 6:51 [TR])
>
> ο ζων πατερ (John 6:57 [TR])

ζων is the participle of ζαο, to live. The participle, coming after the noun, is preceded by the definite article in verse 51. Later on, Jesus uses the wording ο ζων πατερ in verse 57. In this case, the participle, with a preceding article, precedes the noun.

Why did he do this; and what does it tell us ?

[This question has been edited in order to simplify the inquiry.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ἐγώ εἰμι ὁ ἄρτος ὁ ζῶν ὁ ἐκ τοῦ οὐρανοῦ καταβάς

This phrase contains the definite article ὁ three times, indicating that both participles ζῶν and καταβάς modify the noun ἄρτος. An absolutely literal translation would thus be : “I am the living, having-descended-from-heaven, bread”. This sounds uncouth in English; hence the translators have paraphrased the last part of the praise as a relative clause.

Comment: @NigelJ. There is only one statement: a verb + a noun + two participles (verbal adjectives).

Comment: Please see simplified question.

Answer (score -3):

In matters involving the unique person of Christ, language is carefully used - by Jesus himself, and by his apostles.

> *The living Father*, in v57, is the wording used by Jesus Christ of the One who sent him into the world. Yet of himself he says '*I am the bread the living the (or that) out of heaven came down.*

Such delicate wording is necessary to convey the unique Person who came and to convey that the Person was eternal, come in flesh.

> John records similar careful wording in his first epistle. *'that eternal life, which was with the Father and was manifested unto us'.*

These eternal and Divine wonders are couched - most carefully - in language, by the Holy Spirit and they are worthy of examination in detail.